# TeamCity: Number of tests 0 is less then the provided threshold

Tags: python, pytest, teamcity

I have a TeamCity build configuration

And one build step.
Runner type -- Command Line
Step name -- test
Run -- Custom Script
Script:

```
conda create -n my_env python=3.8 pytest
source activate my_env
pytest my_file.py
```

The script is working (I can see results in log `PASSED [100%]`)

But in the "Status" I see

```
TeamCity: Number of tests 0 is less then the provided threshold
```

How can I say TeamCity to count my tests?

Answer (score 1):

Found solution

I have to install special package `teamcity-messages`

```
conda create -n my_env python=3.8 pytest teamcity-messages
```